# Prove \ disprove - if $\int_0^x f(t) \,dt= 10x$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ then $f(x)=10$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ except, maybe, for finite number of values.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Prove \ disprove - if $\int_0^x f(t) \,dt= 10x$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ then $f(x)=10$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ except, maybe, for finite number of values.

It sounds very similar to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus without the continuity, so I guess it is falls on continuity.... I would love to get some help.

Comment: Are we talking Riemann or Lebesgue integrals?

Comment: If $f$ is not continuous on $[0,1]$, then the fundamental theorem does not apply here.

Comment: @Jason the tag was calculus, I bet it is Riemann integral. And this would be a difficult problem in a Calculus course.

Answer (score 4):

If $f$ is continuous, then this follows trivially from the fundamental theorem of calculus.

If $f$ is not continuous, but merely Riemann-integrable, then it is not true: Take
$$
g(t) = \begin{cases}
1 &: t \in \{1/n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}\cup\{0\} \\
0 &: \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $g$ is Riemann integrable and
$$
\int_0^x g(t)dt = 0 \quad\forall x\in [0,1]
$$
So $f := g+10$ satisfies the required conditions, but $f(t) \neq 10$ for infinitely many $t\in [0,1]$.

What you can conclude, however, is that $f=10$ almost everywhere (ie. outside a set of measure zero)